# How to correctly convert xs:time to java date

Tags: java, xml, datetime

I have an xml file which has a field representing a timestamp. The time field is optional and therefore there is no combined datetime field. Using JAXB we map this field to an XMLGregorianCalendar in our java model.

Now my question is how to convert this time to the correct local time (say Europe/Berlin with Daylight Saving) on the date also given in the xml?

The time in the xml file looks as follows:

```
<timeField>14:20:00.0+02:00</timeField>
```

The offset is either not specified (and is assumed to be local time) or it is specified as an offset to UTC.

If I try

```
xmlGregorianCalendarDate.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

then the assumed timezone is `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+02:00",offset=7200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]` which does not take DST into account.

On the contrary if I use `xmlGregorianCalendarDate.toGregorianCalendar(timeZone).getTime();` then it discards the offset from the xml completely in favor of the specified timezone.

Comment: Do you have the date field?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have timezone specified in the XML then it is not possible to guess if it is DST or not (e.g. GMT+2:00 is DST in Berlin, but GMT+2:00 is **not** DST in Kiev so which timezone should the program choose?).

So if you want DST you need to provide the timezone, either in XML or just like you do it above: `xmlGregorianCalendarDate.toGregorianCalendar(timeZone).getTime()`